# Should I use UIViewController or UIView? Making a custom tab bar/nav controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am making an app that has both a bottom bar and a top bar (both are customized) and i want them to stay there the entire length of the app while the middle portion switches between views. But the kicker is at some points in the app, i want to have the top bar and bottom bar slide off the screen and be able to be dragged back on.

What i was thinking was to have one main UIViewController with three UIViews (top bar, middle section, and bottom bar) each running code from their own respective files. Sort of like how a Tab bar works with a nav controller. or do i have that backwards? i dont really know... but any constructive advice helps =)

Im fairly new to xcode and i've been trying to find a way for a few days now, so please dont be too harsh on me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, we build one view controller for each 'screenful' of content. So the basic advice for you would be to make the app in a way where each 'section' is it's own view controller. This is especially important to the MVC paradigm, where your business logic should be in the viewControllers, not the views (just display and interaction logic there). If you had just one view controller, it would get convoluted FAST by trying to manage multiple sections.

A good route may be this: Embed the whole hierarchy in a navigation controller, which gives you the top bar. Then make a custom view controller class which knows how to make your bottom bar, and have each section subclass that.

The side effect is that the bottom bar will be uniquely created for each section VC. If that is not desirable for you, you can explore view controller 'containment'. It is basically a technique for building components *like* the navigation controller, which keep certain elements onscreen for a long time, while exchanging 'content' view controllers for a smaller portion of the screen. It's not the easiest thing to do, and should be considered carefully. However, if you really need to keep *the same instance* of something on screen while other view controllers come and go, it may be the right way to go. That said, consider the other idea first (each section manages it's own bottom bar). You can accomplish it in a way that promotes code re-use, etc.

Comment: So basically you dont want more than one view controller per view?

Comment: Well, to answer appropriately we need to be very clear about the difference between an instance of UIView, and a logical area in your app where you *view* things. In most cases, a UIView instance has exactly one view controller. It is VERY rare to see exceptions. For the area on screen, the rule is: if there is a logical break between two screenfuls of content, they should be managed by two distinct view controllers (each with their own instances of UIView).

Comment: Well i am trying now at building a test app  and what i just did is set up a UIViewController subclass with a 150x150 UIView in it, and loaded a UIViewControlelr subclass into that view... i think you were saying not to use this method but i just wanted to see what it does